# How can I detect double click with physical key in Android?(onKeyMultiple)

Tags: java, android

I'm making Android app with physical keys.
I made keycode 24(can be change to unique key) to do some jobs in my code and want to make it do something else when clicked twice.
I tried onKeyMultiple but it doesn't work at all.
Below is my code with onKeyMultiple

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d("KeyCode Multiple : ", Integer.toString(keyCode) + "," + Integer.toString(repeatCount));
    Intent intent;
    if (keyCode == 24 && event.getRepeatCount() == 2) { // original : 133
        FindActivity.this.finish();
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == 24) {
        event.startTracking();
        Log.d("Main Java Log", "keyevent count : " + Integer.toString(event.getRepeatCount()));
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I first tried if (keyCode == 24 && repeatCount == 2) but it doesn't work, so I made onKeyDown Tracking 24's down and make if (keyCode == 24 && event.getRepeatCount() == 2) but again it doesn't work either.
Plus getReapeatCount() returns 0 whenever I click key 24 once or twice.
I searched for examples that uses onKeyMultiple or use multiple physical keyevent but I couldn't find any.
PLEASE give me some advice or correction to my code.
Truly thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help:

```
private boolean clickedTwice = false;

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == 24) {

if(clickedTwice){

//key was clicked twice
clickedTwice = false;
event.startTracking();

}else{
//key was clicked the first time
clickedTwice = true;

}

return true;

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This worked really nice Thanks! Thus I should get some time limit to prevent clicked_twice for long distance. I just wonder there's no way to use onKeyMultiple? What does this function for?

Comment: If this helped accept the answer so that others with same problem know that this is a solution. GoodLuck. I don't really know the purpose of the other method.

Comment: I've tried your answer on my code and add some timelimit code. It works just right.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code that @Hasan Bou Taam suggested.
And for those who find for fast-double click event, check this :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == 24) {
            if (!clickTwice) {
                starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d("Main Java Log", "Start time : " + String.valueOf(starttime));
                clickTwice = true;
            } else {
                endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d("Main Java Log", "End time : " + String.valueOf(endtime));
                if (endtime - starttime <= 500) { // time interval for second click
                    clickTwice = false;
                    event.startTracking();
                    // do something for doubleclick keyevent
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```